Are there any languages that allow executing shell commands during compilation?
Among the languages available for use on AtCoder, are there any languages that allow executing shell commands during compilation?
I know that Python can achieve this using AOT (Ahead-of-Time) compilation, but I’m looking for a language with even less runtime overhead.

Why do you want to? At present, your question reads a lot like asking how to hack AtCoder by being able to run shell commands on their servers, but I prefer to assume that's not what you're trying to do.

I want to customize C++ compilation options and split the implementation across multiple files.
